# convert the output from Popen to an array

Tags: python

I try to find the process ID on linux OS with python script, with following:

```
  PID = Popen("ps -elf | grep <proc_name>| grep -v grep | awk '{print $4}'", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout
  pid = PID.read()
  pid=int(pid)
```

However, the script does not work if there are more than one PIDs with the same 
The program exits at the  int() function due to '123\n146\n' is not the 10 based int

I then tried the following:
      pid= Pid.read().split()
      print len(pid)
      print pid[0]

It seems to work with the python command line and forms an array of pid =['123','156'], but somehow, it does not work in the script.

any suggestion ?  thanks

Comment: Can you post the revised script that you used (and didn't work)? What does it output instead?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find out *your own* process id? If so, use [`os.getpid()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getpid)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and [`str.splitlines()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
from subprocess import check_output as qx

pids = map(int, qx(["pgrep", procname]).splitlines())
```

To do it without an external process you could try [`psutil`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil/):

```
import psutil # pip install psutil

pids = [p.pid for p in psutil.process_iter() if p.name == procname]
```

Experiment with `p.name`, `p.cmdline` and various comparisons with `procname` to get what you need in your particular case.

And there is also [`os.getpid()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.getpid) to return the current process id.

Comment: Thank you all. I tried to track down some specific processes and  the subproces.check_output() works great for me. Also, a great reminder to use the map().. :)